# npm package becomes private every time I publish

Tags: npm, npm-package

I have an npm organization (paid) that has some private packages. This one, however, should be public. It has been private before.

Recently, every time I publish it, it becomes private again, and I have to manually change it to public in their web UI.

I am publishing using this:

```
(npm version prerelease --preid $BRANCH_NAME && npm run build && npm publish --access public --tag alpha) || read -r -n 1 -p "Press any key to continue"
```

I do **not** have `"private": true` in `package.json`.

Other packages with identical release scripts work as expected. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had this in my `package.json`:

```
"publishConfig": {
    "access": "restricted"
},
```

This is documented here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/using-npm/config#access